# Monotouch App will not launch on Device but works fine in Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I have an iPad application that I have been developing on simulator just fine (xcode 4, md 2.8, mt 5). However, when I try to deploy to the device the application crashes while launching. There are no crash logs in xcode and the console window is not displaying any errors.

However, when I run monotouch from the terminal I get the following output:

Rich-MacBook-Pro:~ rich3$ /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --debugsim=$/private/var/mobile/Applications/31A80564-0CEF-4F4B-AE9D-6A1938510393 
Invalid SDK specified: 3.2 
Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_bool (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,bool) <0xffffffff> 
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.Dispose (bool) <0x0009f> 
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.Finalize () <0x00016> 
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_virtual_void_*this*_ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

```
    0   mtouch                              0x000ec183 WriteZStream + 955779 
    1   mtouch                              0x0001bd4f WriteZStream + 102735 
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9020459b _sigtramp + 43 
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295 
    4   Foundation                          0x9a0603de -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 160 
    5   ???                                 0x027d5884 0x0 + 41769092 
    6   ???                                 0x027d0e40 0x0 + 41750080 
    7   ???                                 0x027d559f 0x0 + 41768351 
    8   ???                                 0x025e5551 0x0 + 39736657 
    9   mtouch                              0x001a76c4 WriteZStream + 1723076 
    10  mtouch                              0x001a968a WriteZStream + 1731210 
    11  mtouch                              0x001a98c4 WriteZStream + 1731780 
    12  mtouch                              0x002735c1 WriteZStream + 2558401 
    13  mtouch                              0x00273677 WriteZStream + 2558583 
    14  mtouch                              0x002b8b0e WriteZStream + 2842382 
    15  mtouch                              0x002f31d8 WriteZStream + 3081688 
    16  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x901aced9 _pthread_start + 335 
    17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x901b06de thread_start + 34
```

Debug info from gdb:

```
/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.1eukTW:1: Error in sourced command file: 
unable to debug self 

================================================================= 
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates 
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application. 
================================================================= 

Abort trap: 6
```

UPDATE:
I finally nailed down my issue to two things.

1. Generics and value-types don't play 
   well together when AOT is used (and that's required to execute on iOS 
   devices). So I needed to change a query: 
   From: 'CSDatabase.RunQuery("select max(VersionNbr) from schema_version").FirstOrDefault();' 
   To: CSDatabase.RunQuery("select max(VersionNbr) from schema_version").First();
2. Next I need to add the argument for the trampolines (-aot "nimt-trampolines=2048") and only linked monotouch sdk during build. That cleared up the rest of my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here.

The second one looks caused by: 
**Invalid SDK specified: 3.2**

Simply you do not have the 3.2 SDK installed (it's not shipped by default with iOS5 SDK). Try the following command:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --debugsim=/path/to/your.app --sdk=5.0
```

and it should work fine.

As for the first issue there's not much detail to help you. If no **crash dump** is produced (it happens, e.g. when not enough memory is available) then try the following:

a) open a **terminal** window on your computer;

b) execute the following command

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch --logdev
```

c) start application on device;

d) make it crash (seems automatic in this case ;-)

e) copy/paste the device log into your question (if small) or fill a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (if large)

Comment: Adding the --sdk=5.0 definitely helped. But what I am seeing on start-up are issues in mono.data.sqlite

Thread started: 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement.BindParameter (Int32 index, Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteParameter param) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement.BindParameters () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Thread started:

Comment: Glad it helped. However the rest of your message only show an incomplete stack trace (missing exception type/message). Please follow my steps and either **edit** your own question (since the error within it is not interesting/fixed) or fill a bug report. Thanks!